# Get the sfdc_networkid when logging in for the first time via Custom External Auth Provider

Tags: auth, digital-experience

I have a custom Auth Provider (Apex class extending `Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass`).

I also have a generated `Auth.RegistrationHandler`.

In the sample code there is a line like so:

```
if(data.attributeMap.containsKey('sfdc_networkid')) {
```

Unfortunately, nowhere in my Auth Provider class am I passed the networkid when user logs in via SSO in their 'Digital Experience' site, and it is not injected into my `data.attributeMap` passed to my reg handler.

If i am not using one of built in Auth Providers, how am i supposed to know which digital experience the user is logging in to?

Comment: There is a static `Network.getNetworkId()` method you should be able to invoke for this. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_network.htm) for more detail. Are you suggesting it doesn't work, because the user isn't yet authenticated?

Comment: @PhilW didn't occur to me to try it :) if you add this as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a static Network.getNetworkId() method you should be able to invoke for this. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_network.htm) for more detail